# How to handle mysql datetime column when the value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a database column 'date_announced' whose value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`,when I try to insert this value to class field I run into error
`Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime"`,how to gracefully handle the code not to throw an exception?

```
date_announced = 0000-00-00 00:00:00

var BuildDetails = new BuildAnnounceDetails();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    BuildDetails.SP = rdr.GetString(0);
    //BuildDetails.BuildID = rdr.GetString(1);
    BuildDetails.CreatedDate = rdr.GetString(1);
    BuildDetails.AnnouncedDate = rdr.GetString(2); **//throws an exception at this line**
    BuildDetails.AnnouncedBy = rdr.GetString(3);
    if (BuildDetails != null)
    {
        BuildAnnounceDetailsInfo.Add(BuildDetails);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Comment: What is the purpose of that 0000-00-00... date? do you want to display it or something?

Comment: when the value is `0000-00-00` I just want to display an empty string

Comment: Perhaps use null instead of 0.

Comment: @STLDeveloper - aren't null values a bad design?rather have a default value?

Comment: @dotnet - not at all.  Nulls are quite useful when a value is unknown.

Comment: @dotnet quite the opposite.  Arbitrary default values are a bad design.  `NULL` is a marker signifying that the column has no value for the row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [GetMySqlDateTime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader-getmysqldatetime) method which has an `IsValidDateTime` property. So in your case:

```
BuildDetails.AnnouncedDate = rdr.GetMySqlDateTime(2).IsValidDateTime?rdr.GetString(2):string.Empty;
```